# How to do two decimal places roundup in java script

Tags: javascript

**input:**

```
11
2.7777777
8.1
```

**Output:**

```
11
2.78
8.1
```

I'd like to round up to 2 decimal places, but only if necessary.

How can I do this in JavaScript?

Comment: Your question is quite unclear will you please elaborate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Math.round(num * 100) / 100`

Comment: This would round to nearest whole integer. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round

Comment: @DanielShillcock No, it wouldn't.

Answer (score -1):

See `toFixed()` documentation here: [toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

```
var num = 2.777777;
if (num.split(".")[1].length > 2){
   num = num.toFixed(2); //2.78
}
```

Comment: This will throw an error if the input is an integer.